# Spring boot with logback

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback

I have created RollingFileAppender via java instead of using logback.xml. Reason behind to switch from logback.xml to java is need to validate the file generation path is writable and if not switch to default path. I am facing following problem, with java code able to successfully create logs for application package, however root level logging gets reset(because of context.reset) is used while creating rollingappender.

It would be great help if you could provide insights on the below.

1. how to use same rolling file appender for Root logger in java. Is it possible to define like that.
   P.S I have tried using same appender but logs are not getting generated for root level, only defined package is getting logged.
2. is it possible to exclude certain loggers if the logger is obtained from Root logger. Logger logger=LoggerContext.getLogger(“ROOT”). If this approach is used all the internal libraries logs are getting logged in file. How to exclude such logging. P.S. since I am using spring context for logging application properties for logback is not getting effective.
3. if to use logback itself is it possible to invoke java method to validate the path is writable and set the path? Any example for this will be helpful. P.S. I have used spring property which is working via logback, but if the value is configured as null or empty, application starting is failed.

Please suggest which option is better, since I have tried max possibilities whichever I can and all the examples leads to application properties not via java.